# AWEBER and captcha integration

Tags: php, captcha

I have a client that wants captcha integrated into a form that posts information to AWABER. It uses his aweber account to collect subscribers. So I have read here http://www.devgarbage.in/2011/01/25/auto-submit-to-aweber/ that AJAX calls to AWEBER can't be made since AWEBER strictly wants the user to press the button (fair enough) and I would have made a script that validates the captcha field locally with PHP and then, upon success, to post the form to aweber... So, just want to check if there are any other solutions to this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send requests across domains without controlling both sides, that is why ajax wont work.  You could send it from your server, but they will likely catch on after every customer who gets added comes from the same IP address.  You can however automatically submit the form with javascript as if they clicked it, after verifying the CAPTCHA was typed correctly.

Comment: How do you suggest verifying the CAPTCHA ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you already have a CAPTCHA system setup?  Doesn't sound like it.  Check out re-captcha, its free and easy to use. (cue the people complaining it shouldn't be recommended as its cracked. it will still stop the majority of people, even the site you are on right now is still using it)

Comment: I have the CAPTCHA already, just didn't got what you meant in the answer. I get it now. Thanks.